# Django manage.py returns ValueError: zero length field name in format

Tags: python, django

I am trying to run a Django application in Python 2.6.6 Django==1.5.5 . But when I try to run

> python manage.py

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 12, in <module>
    print('Your environment is:"{}"'.format(os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']))
ValueError: zero length field name in format
```

Any idea what is wrong? I am also running the same application in another server but with Python 2.7.5 and it works ok.

Note: DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is an environmental variable in both systems

Thanks,

Carlos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python 2.6 doesn't implicitly number the `{}` fields if you leave the numbers out. You need to explicitly specify a `0`:

```
print('Your environment is:"{0}"'.format(os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']))
                             ^
```

Comment: So is this a 2.6 issue? Since the application code is not mine shall I update python to 2.7.x?

Comment: @QLands: Maybe. I don't know much about using Django.